# Why do all other php files give an error message in browser?

Tags: php, apache

**Windows 7 Pro 32 bit • Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13 ] • PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Jun 25 2014 12:40:49) • java version "1.8.0_05" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13) • Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode, sharing) • PostgreSQL 9.3.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit) • FireFox**

I have a index.php setup ( `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`) and a test.php file with the same contents in my apache folder (htdocs). If I access this from another machine I get the output I want, but as soon as I use any other php file with contents like for example `<?php echo "hello"; ?>`, I get "**connection was reset**" error. I tested this `<?php echo "hello"; ?>` in the php console and I get the output I want.

So the question, how can I get my other php files to display just as well as the test.php and the index.php ??

**[EDIT]**

Here's the PHP vars ...

```
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    192.168.28.100
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-US,en;q=0.5
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["PATH"] C:\php;C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
_SERVER["SystemRoot"]   C:\Windows
_SERVER["COMSPEC"]  C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
_SERVER["PATHEXT"]  .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
_SERVER["WINDIR"]   C:\Windows
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] no value
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1h
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  192.168.28.100
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  192.168.28.100
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  192.168.28.110
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    C:/apache/htdocs
_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]   http
_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]   no value
_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    C:/apache/htdocs
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  C:/apache/htdocs/index.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  59522
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /index.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /index.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]   1404983711.068
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1404983711
_SERVER["argv"] 

Array
(
)

_SERVER["argc"] 0
_ENV["ALLUSERSPROFILE"] C:\ProgramData
_ENV["AMDAPPSDKROOT"]   C:\Program Files\AMD APP\
_ENV["APPDATA"] C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
_ENV["CommonProgramFiles"]  C:\Program Files\Common Files
_ENV["ComSpec"] C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
_ENV["FP_NO_HOST_CHECK"]    NO
_ENV["LOCALAPPDATA"]    C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
_ENV["NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"]    2
_ENV["OS"]  Windows_NT
_ENV["Path"]    C:\php;C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
_ENV["PATHEXT"] .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
_ENV["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"]  x86
_ENV["PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"]    x86 Family 16 Model 6 Stepping 3, AuthenticAMD
_ENV["PROCESSOR_LEVEL"] 16
_ENV["PROCESSOR_REVISION"]  0603
_ENV["ProgramData"] C:\ProgramData
_ENV["ProgramFiles"]    C:\Program Files
_ENV["PSModulePath"]    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
_ENV["PUBLIC"]  C:\Users\Public
_ENV["SystemDrive"] C:
_ENV["SystemRoot"]  C:\Windows
_ENV["TEMP"]    C:\Windows\TEMP
_ENV["TMP"] C:\Windows\TEMP
_ENV["USERDOMAIN"]  WORKGROUP
_ENV["USERPROFILE"] C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
_ENV["windir"]  C:\Windows
_ENV["AP_PARENT_PID"]   4920
```

Comment: Guessing you're accessing it via apache? (http://127.0.0.1//) and not file://?

Comment: Yes, via apache over the network. It works fine with 192.168.29.100/test.php or just 192.168.29.100. But as soon as I add any other file it gives that error "connection was reset" or "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Comment: Is the server running Linux or windows?

Comment: The server is running Windows 7 Pro 32 bit

Comment: If you are using `Internet Explorer`, please use another browser, like `Firefox`. `Internet Explorer` usually changes the final page if it finds anything it doesn't please.

Comment: I am using firefox as well, same problem :)

Comment: Can you give an example of another file name you are trying?

Comment: Examples of file names menu.php, versions.php, dbread.php and hey.php

Comment: I tried changing a few settings in the httpd.conf file but that didn't help. Maybe I must build a html frame around the php ?

Comment: I tried changing security persmissions with the entire apache htdocs folder and even shared it with read permissions but that didn't help.

Comment: nevermind, I installed WAMPServer...